# Why is my script returning multiple rows for a case when?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @BranchNum AS INT

SET @StartDate = '2019-10-21'
SET @EndDate = '2019-10-25'
set @BranchNum = '9'

SELECT q.Branch
, q.[Teller Number]
, q.[Account Number]
, COUNT(q.Shares) OVER (PARTITION BY q.[Account Number]) AS [Shares]
, q.SharesBalance
, q.[Share Type]
, q.[Share ID]
, MAX(q.[Debit]) AS [Debit]
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT
s.branch AS [Branch]
, s.CREATEDBYUSER AS [Teller Number]
, acct.accountnumber AS [Account Number]
, COUNT( CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
        AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
        AND (s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
        then s.PARENTACCOUNT
        END) AS [Shares]
, CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL 
    AND (s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
    THEN s.balance 
    else 0
    END AS [SharesBalance]
, CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    THEN s.TYPE
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Share Type]
, CASE WHEN s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.CHARGEOFFDATE is NULL
    then s.ID
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Share ID]
, CASE  
    When c.TYPE in (15,16,17) 
    AND c.STATUS = 1 
    AND c.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND (c.ISSUEDATE >= @StartDate AND c.ISSUEDATE <= @EndDate)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Debit]

from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct
INNER join ARCUSYM000.dbo.savings s
    on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = s.PARENTACCOUNT and s.ProcessDate =     acct.ProcessDate
INNER join arcuSYM000.dbo.CARD c 
    on acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER = c.PARENTACCOUNT and c.ProcessDate =     acct.ProcessDate
where acct.CLOSEDATE is null  
    AND s.CLOSEDATE is null 
    AND s.chargeoffdate is null 
    AND ((s.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND s.OPENDATE <= @EndDate)
    OR (acct.OPENDATE >= @StartDate AND acct.OPENDATE <= @EndDate))
    AND acct.memberstatus = 0 
    AND s.branch is not null 
    AND s.branch IN (@BranchNum)
    AND s.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND acct.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND c.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
GROUP BY s.BRANCH
    , s.CREATEDBYUSER
    , acct.ACCOUNTNUMBER
    , s.CLOSEDATE
    , s.CHARGEOFFDATE
    , s.BALANCE
    , s.TYPE
    , s.ID
    , c.TYPE
    , c.STATUS
    , c.USAGEDATE
    , c.CLOSEDATE
    , c.ISSUEDATE
    , acct.STATEMENTMAILCODE
    , s.SHARECODE
    , s.OVERDRAFTTOLERANCE
    , s.OPENDATE
    , s.PARENTACCOUNT
) q
GROUP BY q.Branch
    , q.[Teller Number]
    , q.[Account Number]
    , q.SharesBalance
    , q.Shares
    , q.[Share Type]
    , q.[Share ID]

ORDER BY q.[Account Number], q.[Teller Number]
```

Right now my script is returning multiple rows for each account on the debit column, when it should only be returning one row.

I'm not sure why it is returning multiple rows for each account since the CARD table only has one result for that account number.

Current Result:
[image: Current Result:]

Desired Result:
[image: Desired Result]

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CARD c
WHERE c.PARENTACCOUNT = '123456'
    AND c.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND c.TYPE in (15,16,17) 
    AND c.STATUS = 1 
    AND c.CLOSEDATE is null
```

When selecting from the CARD table: [image]

Comment: @Larnu, I am using COUNT

Comment: Hard to truly know without a better understanding of your database schema but it's almost assuredly going to be caused by your Inner Joins.

Comment: In the inner query, yes, but not the outer, as it's using the `OVER`; it doesn't use the `GROUP BY`. And the reason you have multiple rows is because you'll have 1 row per group; and you clearly have multiple groups (for example, there are 2 values for `Debit`, so that's 2 groups already).

Comment: Also, the `CASE` expression has nothing to do with the problem, and it'll be related to the `GROUP BY` and lack of aggregation on columns that should be grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following modification:
in SELECT clause

```
SELECT q.Branch
    , q.[Teller Number]
    , q.[Account Number]
    , COUNT(q.Shares) OVER (PARTITION BY q.[Account Number]) AS [Shares]
    , q.SharesBalance
    , q.[Share Type]
    , q.[Share ID]
    , Max(q.[Debit]) [Debit]    ----MODIFIED
```

in GROUP BY clause:

```
GROUP BY q.Branch
    , q.[Teller Number]
    , q.[Account Number]
    , q.SharesBalance
    , q.Shares
    , q.[Share Type]
    , q.[Share ID]
   -- , q.Debit         ---- MODIFIED
```